# Error user.setPassword is not a function (During password reset)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

My express app users passport for Authentication. Authentication works. I am trying to implement password reset and getting the following error.

TypeError: user.setPassword is not a function

I have gone through stackoverflow and other sites for this error and all point to "passport-local-mongoose", but I have that module already. Not sure what else is wrong in here:

Here is my .\models\user.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    fullname: String,
    role: String,
    status: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose); 
module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

here is my form in the .\views\admusrpwreset.ejs

```
            <form action="/admusrpwreset/<%= user._id %>" method="POST">
                    <UL>
                        <Li>
                            Username  : <span class="admstudyinput"><%= user.username %></span>
                        </Li>
                        <Li>
                            Password : 
                            <input class="admstudyinput" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Minumum 8 characters">
                        </Li>
                        <Li>
                            Confirm : 
                            <input class="admstudyinput" type="password" name="confirm" placeholder="Confirm the password">
                        </Li>
                        <Li>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark" type="submit">RESET</button>
                        </Li>
                    </UL> 
            </form>
```

Here is the POST route that the above form sends the data to:
Its in .\routes\auth.js

```
router.post("/admusrpwreset/:id", isLoggedinAdmin, function(req, res){
    user.findOne(req.params.id, function(err,returneduser){
          if(!user){
              console.log("No user exists");
          }
          if (req.body.password === req.body.confirm){
                user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err) {
                    user.save(function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        res.redirect("/adminuser");
                    });
                });
          } else {
             console.log("Passwords do not match")       ;
             res.redirect("/adminuser");
          }
    });
});
```

I am expecting the password to be reset. I can't see what I am doing wrong. 
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

setPassword is a schema method, it is used on an instance of a model, not the model itself. You are using setPassword with the user Model.Thats why the error is showing

if you want to change the password you need to use the returneduser object

```
router.post("/admusrpwreset/:id", isLoggedinAdmin, function(req, res){
user.findOne(req.params.id, function(err,returneduser){
      if(!user){
          console.log("No user exists");
      }
      if (req.body.password === req.body.confirm){
            returneduser.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err) {
                returneduser.save(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect("/adminuser");
                });
            });
      } else {
         console.log("Passwords do not match")       ;
         res.redirect("/adminuser");
      }
});
```

});

Comment: It is a schema mode. It see my user.js file, you can see i do userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);. module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);That should give access to all the methods to "users".

Comment: This code works bacause i used it. I also reproduced your error by directly using usermodel and error goes away if you if you use an instance. Please check returneduser is not empty otherwise share your passport auth code and login code part